# How to automatically flip images vertically in android?

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper, flip

I have implemented FlipView, which is working fine. Now what i want to do is to flip all the images automatically with certain time interval.
I have check `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`, but didn't get that.

Any suggestions.
Please help me.

Comment: You can look at card flip animation http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Comment: I saw that, but it is not working for 10+ images

Comment: I don't want to flip/rotate a single image, i am having 10+ images. Which i need to flip one by one vertically

Comment: Yes: `i need to flip one by one` means: simply **repeat 10 times** the same method.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks.